# How fetch record in Hibernate One to Many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many

I have 2 POJO classes: `Ownerdetials` (Parent table)
and `Vehiclemaster` (Child table).
I want to get all `oname` (means Ownername) which belong to `Vehicle` table.

My classes:

**Ownerdetails.java:**

```
public class Ownerdetails  implements java.io.Serializable {
    private Integer ownerid;
    private String oname;
    private String panno;
    private String mobile;
    private String address;
    private String pincode;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String country;
    private String accno;
    private String bankname;
    private String branch;
    private String ifccode;
    private Set vehiclemasters = new HashSet(0);
    //Setter and Getter method 
 }
```

**Vehiclemaster.java:**

```
public class Vehiclemaster  implements java.io.Serializable {
    private Integer vid;
    private Ownerdetails ownerdetails;
    private String vno;
    private String vname;
    private String driverlicense;
    private String unladenWeight;
    private String drivername;
    private String vtype;
    private String inscompname;
    private String instype;
    private String insfrom;
    private String insto;
    private String fitnessdatefrom;
    private String fitnessdateto;
    //Setter and Getter Method
}
```

Below is my SQL Query, how to convert in Hibernate HQL Query?

```
select ownerdetails.oname from ownerdetails,vehiclemaster 
WHERE ownerdetails.ownerid=vehiclemaster.ownerid;
```

I googled it, but did not get proper result.

Answer (score 0):

**Mappings**

```
public class Ownerdetails  implements java.io.Serializable {

  @Id
  private Integer ownerid;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ownerdetails")
  private Set<Vehiclemaster> vehiclemasters = new HashSet(0);

}

public class Vehiclemaster  implements java.io.Serializable {

   @Id
   private Integer vid;

   @ManyToOne 
   @JoinColumn(name = "ownerid")
   private Ownerdetails ownerdetails;

}
```

**Query**

```
select distinct od.oname 
from Ownerdetails od
   inner join od.vehiclemasters vm
where vm.vname = 'name'  // optional
```

Comment: Thanks Maciej Kowalski..but not getting " where vm.vname = 'name' " line .  if ' name ' data member does not exists in pojo classes so how could you take.

Comment: private String vname; again this is just and example of using where if needed

Comment: Does my answer address your question and fixes your probelm?